# Oracle Full Text Index Order by clause gives error

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this oracle full text index:

```
CREATE INDEX TEXTINDEX ON "DatabaseName"."Transactions"("BuyerName") 
INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CONTEXT
```

This index is created this way.

When I try to add `order by` clause it gives me this error:

> column name TransactionId is not a valid section name

The new statement with order by clause is:

```
 CREATE INDEX TEXTINDEX ON "DatabaseName"."Transactions"("BuyerName") 
 INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CONTEXT 
 order by "TransactionId"
```

The TransactionId column is primary key of type `NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL`
I tried to write it like

```
order by "FSCTR"."TransactionId"
order by "PK_Transactions"
order by "PK_Transactions_TransactionId"
order by TransactionId
```

Nothing is working!

Comment: Because in oracle docs site is shown like that:  https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CCAPP/GUID-74C5496E-D491-4EC6-B918-EA7B0B71BA40.htm

Comment: So it seems the problem is a matter of your table structure. Please post the DDL for the table (or if it's too large at least a version of it which includes all the columns referenced in the index statement).

Answer (score 0):

How it turned out `order by` clause can be applied on newly created column